# Is there a design pattern or any typical solution for interrupting program execution without using exceptions?

Tags: java, design-patterns, architecture

I have method *A* called from another method of another class, which called from another method, etc. I have a condition in my *A* method and I want to do two things if it evaluates to false:

1. print a certain message in a console
2. interrupt program execution after that

The program must print an error message and then exit. I can implement it using exceptions, but I shouldn't, because it's not an exceptional case.
Another way to do what I want is by using return value of method A. But in this case, I should use the return value of a method, calling method A, and so on. All the methods from the sequence of calls should return a value and no one of them can be ignored. I will have to write plenty of

`if (!func()) return false;`

and will be forced to print messages immediately before the first 'return' (using exceptions it is possible to print their own messages from a place where they were caught).

Is there any solution for my problem? Maybe there's something absolutely wrong in the way I'm thinking...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to terminate a java program, there's an `exit()` method, both in class [Runtime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html) and class [System](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html).